# Angular 8 post ngFor mat-select

Tags: typescript, angular

На основе количества елементов в массиве `fields` генерирую такое же количество `mat-select`, но как теперь например с помощью post запроса отправить все выбранные в этих `mat-select` значения? Количество елементов может же менятся, как обойтись без хардкода? Спасибо.

**app.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="uploadForm">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let field of fields">
    <br />
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>{{field.label}}</mat-label>
      <mat-select [id]="field.name">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of field.options" [value]="option">
          {{option}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
  <br />
  <button mat-button (click)="Submit()" type="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  uploadForm: FormGroup;  
  public fields: any[];

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.uploadForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      profile: ['']
    });

    this.fields = [
      { label: "Drill Bit Type", name: "drillBitType", options: ["Masonry", "SDS", "Universal"] },
      { label: "Drill Bit SharpAngel", name: "drillBitSharpAngel", options: ["118", "120", "135"] },
      { label: "Drill Bit Sharp Direction", name: "drillBitSharpDirection", options: ["Left", "Right"] }]
  }
  Submit() {
  //Как передать сюда все выбранные значения из всех mat-select?
  }
}
```

Comment: получить доступ ко всем инстансам `mat-select` через `ViewChildren`, пройтись в цикле и собрать `matSelect.selected`, самое быстрое решение

Comment: @overthesanity, а можете запостить пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получаешь доступ ко всем инстансам `MatSelect` через `ViewChildren`:

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChildren(MatSelect) matSelects: QueryList<MatSelect>;
}
```

Angular автоматически будет апдейтить `matSelects`, как бы они не изменялись. Далее в своем методе `submit` итерируешь `matSelects` и собираешь все `selected` свойства:

```
export class AppComponent {
  submit(): void {
    const selectedOptions: MatOption[] = this.matSelects
      .toArray()
      .map(matSelect => matSelect.selected as MatOption);
  }
}
```

Под `selected` может быть `MatOption | MatOption[]`, кастую только для примера.

Если нужно получить все значения, то опять же маппишь на `selected.value`:

```
export class AppComponent {
  submit(): void {
    const values = this.matSelects
      .toArray()
      .map(matSelect => matSelect.selected as MatOption);
      .map(matOption => matOption.value);
  }
}
```

Если у тебя `fields.length === 3`, то массив `values` будет содержать одно из значений массивов `options`, например:

```
(3) ["Masonry", "118", "Left"]
```

Это конечно если каждый `mat-option` имеет выбранное значение. Если хотя бы 1 `mat-option` не имеет выбранного значения, то код выше приведет к эксепшену, поэтому лучше используй пример с `selectedOptions`.

Можно конечно же добавить фильтрацию:

```
export class AppComponent {
  submit(): void {
    const values = this.matSelects
      .toArray()
      .map(matSelect => matSelect.selected as MatOption)
      .filter(matOption => matOption !== undefined)
      .map(matOption => matOption.value);
  }
}
```

Но я не знаю какую задачу ты решаешь.

---

Если изначально разрабатывать правильно, то такие задачи реализуются через `FormArray`, но это совсем другая история.

Comment: а какой подход самый верный, если например в контейнер еще добавить несколько типов mat input и прочих?

Comment: @A191919 все максимально зависит от поставленной задачи. В твоем случае это самое быстрое решение и уже велосипед можно не придумывать, но в следующие разы старайся максимально связывать все с реактивной формой

Comment: @A191919 мне конечно немного лень гуглить, но вот наткнулся на первую ссылку - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/angular-material-design-components-with-reactive-form-part-2/. Код конечно шлак, но поверхностно можно взглянуть, чтоб в будущем знать как делать, думаю если погуглишь, то найдешь, то что ищешь